What features allow a character to maximize a damage roll?
Some abilities apply maximum damage to an attack that's made.
One example of this is a Tempest Domain Cleric's Channel Divinity, which allows them to deal the maximum damage (or automatically have maximum damage dice) for the next Thunder or Lightning spell attack cast.
This also happens in one of the Wild Magic Sorcerer's table rolls, but applies it to the first damaging spell cast within a minute of the effect being rolled on the Wild Magic table.
My question is, are there any other instances of abilities or such that have similar effects and apply maximum damage? This counts for any magic items, character class options, monster abilities, etc.

Evocation Wizard's Overchannel
Source: Player's Handbook

Starting at 14th level, you can increase the power of your simpler spells. When you cast a wizard spell of 1st through 5th level that deals damage, you can deal maximum damage with that spell.
The first time you do so, you suffer no adverse effect. If you use this feature again before you finish a long rest, you take 2d12 necrotic damage for each level of the spell, immediately after you cast it. Each time you use this feature again before finishing a long rest, the necrotic damage per spell level increases by 1d12. This damage ignores resistance and immunity.

Sword of Sharpness
Source: DMG

When you attack an object with this magic sword and hit, maximize your weapon damage dice against the target.

Potion of Maximum Power
Source: Explorer's Guide to Wildemount

Potion, rare
The first time you cast a damage-dealing spell of 4th level or lower within 1 minute after drinking the potion, instead of rolling dice to determine the damage dealt, you can instead use the highest number possible for each die.
This glowing purple liquid smells of sugar and plum, but it has a muddy taste.

Rod of Hellish Flames
Source: The Book of Many Things

Rod, Very Rare (requires attunement by a spellcaster)
[…]
Surge of Brimstone. Whenever you cast a spell that deals fire or necrotic damage, you can use the rod to deal the maximum damage instead of rolling. Once this property is used, it can't be used again until the next dawn.


I looked only in the PHB, DMG, and MM - but made this a wiki assuming there were many more answers.  Surely in all the non-core content there is another magic items or character class option that maximizes damage?

I added the Potion of Maximum Power.

Added Rod of Hellish Flames
